# Autoencoder failed to find anomaaly

Tags: python, keras, image-processing, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

We're using the following architecture for anomaly-finding-

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(80,80,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6))

#-----------------#

model.add(Dense(32,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(51200,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape ((20 ,20 ,128)))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D ((2 ,2)))
model.add(Conv2D (128,  kernel_size =(3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D ((2 ,2)))
model.add(Conv2D (3,  kernel_size =(3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Reshape ((3 ,6400)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Reshape ((80,80,3)))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

We've two sets of images, 1000 images of [TypeA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AimSY.jpg) & 5400 images of [TypeB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZvXf.jpg).
Now when we're training our autoencoder on typeB images and testing on typeA images, mean square error of typeB is coming out to be greater than that of typeA. Since, they are visually different, mse in case of typeB should have been smaller than that of typeA.

Is there any problem in my architecture? What should I change in the architecture to get the result right? Please suggest...

Comment: This seems like a classification problem. Why are you using anomaly detection instead of classification? What pre-processing steps are you using on the images?

Comment: TypeA image is just a sample anomaly image, we're trying to see whether our anomaly finder is working or not. We have normalized the pixels- that's the only pre-processing step we've used.